# How to check Conway's Game Of Life Code - Glider Gun

Tags: javascript, conways-game-of-life

I have written code of Conway's Game Of Life with JS and I'm pretty sure something is wrong. I'm trying to imitate Gosper glider gun, but even when starting with the right pattern, i can't built any gliders.
I wrote an interface with buttons to toggle, stop and clear the game, and also a button that initializes the game to the pattern of the glider gun

I couldn't fit the table in full into the question here - need to add extra rows for it to work

```js
        var main = document.getElementById("main");
document.getElementById("toggle").setAttribute("onclick", "toggleTable()");
document.getElementById("stop").setAttribute("onclick", "stopTable()");
document.getElementById("setGun").setAttribute("onclick", "setGun()");
document.getElementById("clear1").setAttribute("onclick", "clear1()");

for (var i = 0; i < main.rows.length; i++) {
    var currow = main.rows[i];
    for (var f = 0; f < currow.cells.length; f++)
        currow.cells[f].setAttribute("onclick", "changeColor(this)");
}

function changeColor(item) {
    item.classList.toggle("clicked");
}

function clear1() {
    for (var i = 0; i < main.rows.length; i++) {
        var currow = main.rows[i];
        for (var f = 0; f < currow.cells.length; f++)
            main.rows[i].cells[f].classList.remove("clicked");
    }
}

function setGun() {
    changeColor(main.rows[3].cells[36]);
    changeColor(main.rows[3].cells[37]);
    changeColor(main.rows[4].cells[36]);
    changeColor(main.rows[4].cells[37]);

    changeColor(main.rows[1].cells[26]);
    changeColor(main.rows[2].cells[26]);
    changeColor(main.rows[2].cells[24]);
    changeColor(main.rows[3].cells[23]);
    changeColor(main.rows[3].cells[22]);
    changeColor(main.rows[4].cells[23]);
    changeColor(main.rows[4].cells[22]);
    changeColor(main.rows[5].cells[23]);
    changeColor(main.rows[5].cells[22]);
    changeColor(main.rows[6].cells[24]);
    changeColor(main.rows[6].cells[26]);
    changeColor(main.rows[7].cells[26]);

    changeColor(main.rows[5].cells[2]);
    changeColor(main.rows[5].cells[3]);
    changeColor(main.rows[6].cells[2]);
    changeColor(main.rows[6].cells[3]);

    changeColor(main.rows[3].cells[15]);
    changeColor(main.rows[3].cells[14]);
    changeColor(main.rows[4].cells[13]);
    changeColor(main.rows[5].cells[12]);
    changeColor(main.rows[6].cells[12]);
    changeColor(main.rows[7].cells[12]);
    changeColor(main.rows[8].cells[13]);
    changeColor(main.rows[9].cells[14]);
    changeColor(main.rows[9].cells[15]);
    changeColor(main.rows[6].cells[16]);
    changeColor(main.rows[4].cells[17]);
    changeColor(main.rows[8].cells[17]);
    changeColor(main.rows[5].cells[18]);
    changeColor(main.rows[6].cells[18]);
    changeColor(main.rows[7].cells[18]);
    changeColor(main.rows[6].cells[19]);


}

function calcNeigh(row, cell) {

    var countNeigh = 0;
    if ((row - 1 != -1 && row - 1 < main.rows.length && cell - 1 != -1 && cell - 1 < main.rows[row].cells.length) && main.rows[row - 1].cells[cell - 1].classList.contains("clicked"))
        countNeigh++
    if ((row - 1 != -1 && row - 1 < main.rows.length) && main.rows[row - 1].cells[cell].classList.contains("clicked"))
        countNeigh++
    if ((row - 1 != -1 && row - 1 < main.rows.length && cell + 1 < main.rows[row].cells.length) && main.rows[row - 1].cells[cell + 1].classList.contains("clicked"))
        countNeigh++
    if ((cell - 1 != -1) && main.rows[row].cells[cell - 1].classList.contains("clicked"))
        countNeigh++
    if ((cell + 1 != -1 && cell + 1 < main.rows[row].cells.length) && main.rows[row].cells[cell + 1].classList.contains("clicked"))
        countNeigh++
    if ((row + 1 < main.rows.length && cell - 1 != -1) && main.rows[row + 1].cells[cell - 1].classList.contains("clicked"))
        countNeigh++
    if ((row + 1 < main.rows.length) && main.rows[row + 1].cells[cell].classList.contains("clicked"))
        countNeigh++
    if ((row + 1 < main.rows.length && cell + 1 < main.rows[row].cells.length) && main.rows[row + 1].cells[cell + 1].classList.contains("clicked"))
        countNeigh++
    return countNeigh;
}
function isAlive(i, f) {
    if (main.rows[i].cells[f].classList.contains("clicked"))
        return true;
    else return false;
}

function liveOrDie(neigh, i, f) {
    if (isAlive(i, f)) {
        if (neigh > 3 || neigh < 2)
            main.rows[i].cells[f].classList.remove("clicked");
    }
    else if (neigh == 3)
        main.rows[i].cells[f].classList.add("clicked");
}
var run;
function toggleTable() {
    run = setInterval(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < main.rows.length; i++) {
            var currow = main.rows[i];
            for (var f = 0; f < currow.cells.length; f++) {
                liveOrDie(calcNeigh(i, f), i, f);
            }
        }
    }, 200);

}

function stopTable() {
    clearInterval(run);
}
```

```css
        #main td {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            border: 1px solid silver;
        }

        #main {
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .clicked {
            background-color: black;
        }

        #toggle {
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: navy;
        }
        #stop {
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        #setGun {
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: orchid;
        }

        #clear1 {
            width: 200px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
    <table id="main">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="toggle">toggle</div>
    <div id="stop">stop</div>
    <div id="setGun">setGun</div>
    <div id="clear1">clear</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code updates the cells, while their previous state is still needed to calculate the next state of some neighboring cells, so the calculation for those cells will be wrong.

You need to make sure that all calculations (`neigh`) are done on a snapshot of the "generation" and not on a mutating state.

Other remarks on your code:

- Don't use the DOM to maintain the state of the game. Instead maintain the state in an array data structure, and only write to the DOM (not read from it).
- Don't set "onclick" attributes. Instead use `addEventListener`
- Don't use the pattern `if <boolean expression> return true; else return false` (like you did in `isAlive`). Instead, just return the boolean expression.
- Avoid code repetition, like in `setGun`, where you can make the logic more data-driven: put the involved values in an array, and then loop over that array to initialise the game

Here is what I would make of your code:

```js
const main = document.getElementById("main");

// Create a memory data structure for the real state of the game
const rowCount = 15, colCount = 50;
let grid = Array.from({length: rowCount}, row => Array(colCount).fill(false));
// Build table dynamically to save repetition in static HTML
main.innerHTML = ("<tr>" + "<td><\/td>".repeat(colCount) + "</tr>").repeat(rowCount);

document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", startAnimation);
document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", stopAnimation);
document.getElementById("setGun").addEventListener("click", setGun);
document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", clear);
main.addEventListener("click", e => changeColor(e.target.cellIndex, e.target.parentNode.rowIndex));

// Define constant for some configuration:
const GUN = `
--------------------------X
------------------------X-X
--------------XX------XX------------XX
-------------X---X----XX------------XX
--XX--------X-----X---XX
--XX--------X---X-XX----X-X
------------X-----X-------X
-------------X---X
--------------XX`;

// This function alone is responsible for any output
function display() {
    grid.forEach((row, y) =>
        row.forEach((cell, x) =>
            main.rows[y].cells[x].classList.toggle("clicked", cell)
        )
    );
}

function changeColor(x, y) {
    grid[y][x] = !grid[y][x];
    display();
}

function clear() {
    stopAnimation();
    grid.forEach(row => row.fill(false));
    display();
}

function setFromString(s) {
    clear();
    s.match(/\S+/g).forEach((line, y) => {
        grid[y].forEach((_, x, row) => row[x] = line[x] == "X")
    });
    display();
}

function setGun() {
    setFromString(GUN);
}

function calcNeigh(x, y) {
    return [[x-1,y-1], [x,y-1], [x+1,y-1], [x-1,y], [x+1,y], [x-1,y+1], [x,y+1], [x+1,y+1]]
          .reduce((sum, [x, y]) => sum + isAlive(x, y), 0);
}

function isAlive(x, y) {
    return !!grid[y]?.[x];
}

function liveOrDie(neigh, x, y) {
    return neigh == 2 ? isAlive(x, y) : neigh == 3;
}

function nextGeneration() {
    // grid is updated with a new 2D array, so there is no interference!
    grid = grid.map((row, y) => 
        row.map((cell, x) => liveOrDie(calcNeigh(x, y), x, y))
    );
    display();
}

let run;

function startAnimation() {
    stopAnimation(); // Make sure to first stop the current timer
    run = setInterval(nextGeneration, 200);
}

function stopAnimation() {
    clearInterval(run);
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse }

#main td {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

#main {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.clicked { background-color: black; }

button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
}

#toggle { background-color: cyan;   }
#stop   { background-color: green;  }
#setGun { background-color: orchid; }
#clear  { background-color: white;  }
```

```html
<table id="main"></table>
<button id="toggle">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="setGun">Set Gun</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```